# ¿Cómo guardar los cambios en un radio button?

Tags: php, html

> Actualizo mi Post

Utilizando lo que me comento el usuario maduranma aplique el codigo pero tengo una duda/problema no se actualiza el `$_SESSION['checked']` tal vez algo coloque mal o no se

```php
<?php 
if(isset($_SESSION['checked']))
    $_SESSION['checked'] = true;
if(isset($_POST['switch']))
    $_SESSION['checked'] = $_POST['switch'] == 'no';
?>
```

```html
<input type="radio" <?php echo $_SESSION['checked'] ? 'checked' : ''; ?> value="yes" id="yes" name="switch" class="btn-switch__radio btn-switch__radio_yes" />

<input type="radio" value="no" <?php echo $_SESSION['checked'] ? '' : 'checked'; ?> id="no" name="switch" class="btn-switch__radio btn-switch__radio_no" />

<label for="yes" class="btn-switch__label btn-switch__label_yes"><span class="btn-switch__txt"><i class="fas fa-moon"></i></span></label>

<label for="no" class="btn-switch__label btn-switch__label_no"><span class="btn-switch__txt"><i class="fas fa-sun"></i></span></label>
```

Answer (score 4):

En primer lugar, si son dos opciones relacionadas, deben tener el mismo `name`, es decir, en este caso, ambos `Radio Buttons` deberían tener `name="darkmode"`para que puedan los usuarios seleccionar uno u otro, de lo contrario actuarían meramente como un `checkbox`.

Lo más óptimo sería sustituir el if por uno ternario de forma que quedaría así:

```
<input type="radio" name="darkmode" value="si" <?php echo $_SESSION['checked'] ? 'checked' : ''; ?>> Si
<input type="radio" name="darkmode" value="no" <?php echo $_SESSION['checked'] ? '' : 'checked'; ?>> No
```

En la parte superior, posterior al `session_start()` y para que tenga un valor por defecto (habiendo otras soluciones), quedaría:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['checked']))
    $_SESSION['checked'] = true; // Dark mode por defecto

if(isset($_POST['darkmode']))
    $_SESSION['checked'] = $_POST['darkmode'] == 'si'; // Si es 'si' será true, de lo contrario false (así filtras inputs indeseados).
?>
```

P.D: En cualquier caso, utilizaría otro nombre para la variable que guardes en la sesión (por ejemplo `$_SESSION['darkmode']`), e incluso guardaría la preferencia del usuario en la base de datos donde albergaría el valor por defecto, de forma que no dependa de la sesión.

Comment: Correcto todo lo que dices, agregar, si me lo permites, que html ya se encarga de pintar el radio button, y despintar el otro, no es nada optimo delegar esa tarea en PHP. Y repito que lo dices es super correcto.

Comment: no logro que se guarde en el $_SESSION[]

Comment: Te he dado el código que lo guarda en `$_SESSION['checked']`. Recuerda que `session_start();` debe estar al principio para que pueda enviar los headers.

Comment: @Srsole la forma de guardar un valor por defecto es hacerlo en PHP o JavaScript. Y si añadimos que se quiere guardar por usuario en una BBDD, de alguna forma el backend se tiene que encargar sí o sí.

En este caso solo utiliza PHP y HTML, la única forma de marcar uno u otro input es ponerle checked o no, sea una o 200 opciones, en cada input hay que añadir el checked o no.

Comment: @maduranma cuando mandamos, por post, por ejemplo, un control de tipo checked, este es un array de los mismos, cada uno con sus respectivas propiedades-

Comment: @Srsole en un tipo radio solo se envía el nombre común de los input y el valor del que está marcado, el cual será único. No se envía ningún array.